# Running JConsole on MainFrame

Tags: mainframe, jconsole

Please, could anyone tell me if it is possible to run JConsole on MainFrame? If it does, should I use the same default port: 11298? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean on an IBM Mainframe, like the tag says?

Comment: Yes, @BillWoodger. Thanks!

Comment: Then talk to your technical support staff about what is installed at your site and how you access it.